# Ms Exchange Online | Regex in Transport Rule

Tags: regex, office365, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I want to create a Regex Transport rule for the email with Subject **1365 1049126 9003175245 19382_ST03**

I want to check if the subject contains 900 in the third group of characters and the numbers after 900 are dynamic and is a single word.

For example:
Subject 1 - **1365 1049126 9003175245 19382_ST03**

Subject 2 - **2455 3245626 9003175000 19382_ST03**

Subject 3 - **4567 4449126 9003005030 19382_ST03**

How do I set this in regular expression? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this: `^[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{7}\s900[0-9]{7}\s\w{10}$`
`^` Matches start of strings
`[0-9]{4}\s` Matches 4 digits and whitespace after them
`[0-9]{7}\s` Does the same but for 7 digits
`900[0-9]{7}\s` <-- This matches 900 and 7 digits and whitespace
`\w{10}s` Matches 10 word characters
`$` Matches end of string
If these groups are not ONLY digits, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\w`

Comment: I haven't tested this but correct me if I'm wrong, Exchange Regular Expressions doesn't support half of the stuff that was marked as an answer here, feels like you ran this on some Regex testing platform, answered and called it a day, Sheena seems to not even have tested this either to accept this, for example, [ and ] are parsed as regular characters in this syntax, see http://blog.chrislehr.com/2014/11/using-regular-expressions-in-exchange.html there is a snipped from a doc Microsoft doesn't have up anymore.